# Problem to parse some elements with xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, pandas, xml, dataframe, elementtree

I hope you are well. I am facing some difficulties related to my parser. Indeed, my dataset looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<bugrepository name="AspectJ">
  <bug id="28974" opendate="2003-1-3 10:28:00" fixdate="2003-1-14 14:30:00">
    <buginformation>
      <summary>"Compiler error when introducing a ""final"" field"</summary>
      <description>The aspecs the problem...</description>
    </buginformation>
    <fixedFiles>
      <file>org.aspectj/modules/weaver/src/org/aspectj/weaver/AjcMemberMaker.java</file>
    </fixedFiles>
  </bug>

  <bug id="28919" opendate="2002-12-30 16:40:00" fixdate="2003-1-14 15:06:00">
    <buginformation>
      <summary>waever tries to weave into native methods ...</summary>
      <description>If youat org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.burce</description>
    </buginformation>
    <fixedFiles>
      <file>org.aspectj/modules/weaver/src/org/aspectj/weaver/bcel/LazyMethodGen.java</file>
    </fixedFiles>
  </bug>
  
  <bug id="29186" opendate="2003-1-8 21:22:00" fixdate="2003-1-14 16:43:00">
    <buginformation>
      <summary>ajc -emacssym chokes on pointcut that includes an intertype method</summary>
      <description>This ;void Foo.ajc$before$Foo</description>
    </buginformation>
    <fixedFiles>
      <file>org.aspectj/modules/weaver/src/org/aspectj/weaver/Lint.java</file>
      <file>org.aspectj/modules/weaver/src/org/aspectj/weaver/Shadow.java</file>
      <file>org.aspectj/modules/weaver/src/org/aspectj/weaver/bcel/BcelWeaver.java</file>
    </fixedFiles>
  </bug>
  
  <bug id="29769" opendate="2003-1-19 11:42:00" fixdate="2003-1-24 21:17:00">
    <buginformation>
      <summary>Ajde does not support new AspectJ 1.1 compiler options</summary>
      <description>The org.aspectj.ajpiler. This enhancement is needed byort.</description>
    </buginformation>
    <fixedFiles>
      <file>org.aspectj/modules/ajde/testdata/examples/figures-coverage/figures/Figure.java</file>
      <file>org.aspectj/modules/ajde/testsrc/org/aspectj/ajde/AjdeTests.java</file>
      <file>org.aspectj/modules/ajde/testsrc/org/aspectj/ajde/ui/StructureViewManagerTest.java</file>
      <file>org.aspectj/modules/org.aspectj.ajdt.core/src/org/aspectj/ajdt/ajc/BuildArgParser.java</file>
      <file>org.aspectj/modules/org.aspectj.ajdt.core/src/org/aspectj/ajdt/internal/core/builder/AjBuildConfig.java</file>
      <file>org.aspectj/modules/org.aspectj.ajdt.core/testsrc/org/aspectj/ajdt/ajc/BuildArgParserTestCase.java</file>
    </fixedFiles>
  </bug>
  <bug id="29959" opendate="2003-1-22 7:10:00" fixdate="2003-2-13 16:00:00">
    <buginformation>
      <summary>super call in intertype method declaration body causes VerifyError</summary>
      <description>AspectJ Compiler 1.1 showstopper</description>
    </buginformation>
    <fixedFiles>
      <file>org.aspectj/modules/org.aspectj.ajdt.core/src/org/compiler/ast/InterTypeConstructorDeclaration.java</file>
      <file>org.aspectj/modules/org.aspectj.ajdt.core/src/org/aspectj/ajdt/internal/compiler/ast/SuperFixerVisitor.java</file>
      <file>org.aspectj/modules/org.aspectj.ajdt.core/src/org/aspectj/ajdt/internal/compiler/lookup/InterTypeMethodBinding.java</file>
      <file>org.aspectj/modules/tests/bugs/SuperToIntro.java</file>
    </fixedFiles>
  </bug>
</bugrepository>
```

I would like to be able to recover some elements of the dataset to use them with Pandas in a dataframe.

**First problem** is to take all the sub-elements  from the  tag in list form.

Actually my code, only retrieves the first  element and ignores the others or can retrieves all of them but not structured as you can see in theses pictures :
[here only the empty ([]) lists without content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjCFJ.png)

The code :

```
import pandas as pd 
from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse

document = parse('dataset.xml')
summary = []
description = []
fixedfile = []

for item in document.iterfind('bug'):
    summary.append(item.findtext('buginformation/summary'))
    description.append(item.findtext('buginformation/description'))
    fixedfile.append(item.findall('fixedFiles/file'))
    
#df = pd.DataFrame({'summary':summary, 'description':description, 'fixed_files':fixedfile})
df = pd.DataFrame({'fixed_files': fixedfile})
df
```

[here only the first  element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sr6CF.png)

The code :

```
import pandas as pd 
from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse

document = parse('dataset.xml')
summary = []
description = []
fixedfile = []

for item in document.iterfind('bug'):
    summary.append(item.findtext('buginformation/summary'))
    description.append(item.findtext('buginformation/description'))
    fixedfile.append(item.findtext('fixedFiles/file'))
    
#df = pd.DataFrame({'summary':summary, 'description':description, 'fixed_files':fixedfile})
df = pd.DataFrame({'fixed_files': fixedfile})
df
```

I found here ["Problem traversing XML tree with Python xml.etree.ElementTree"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54466511/problem-traversing-xml-tree-with-python-xml-etree-elementtree) a solution that I adapt to my case, it works but not like I want (list of list per element), I can load all the  element but individually.

The code :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd 

xmldoc = ET.parse('dataset.xml')
root = xmldoc.getroot()
summary = []
description = []
fixedfile = []

for bug in xmldoc.iter(tag='bug'): 
    
    #for item in document.iterfind('bug'):
    #summary.append(item.findtext('buginformation/summary'))
    #description.append(item.findtext('buginformation/description'))
    
    for file in bug.iterfind('./fixedFiles/file'):
    
           fixedfile.append([file.text])
        
fixedfile
#df = pd.DataFrame({'summary':summary, 'description':description, 'fixed_files':fixedfile})
df = pd.DataFrame({'fixed_files': fixedfile})
df
```

When I want to iterate the others  columns (summary, description) of my dataframe, I get the following error message:
ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length

**Second problem**, being able to select for example all  tags that have 2 or 3  sub-elements.

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the files in a list that are associated with the description and summary, add them to a new list for each bug.

**Try:**

```python
import pandas as pd
from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse

document = parse('dataset.xml')
summary = []
description = []
fixedfile = []

for item in document.iterfind('bug'):
    summary.append(item.findtext('buginformation/summary'))
    description.append(item.findtext('buginformation/description'))
    fixedfile.append([elt.text for elt in item.findall('fixedFiles/file')])

df = pd.DataFrame({'summary': summary,
                   'description': description,
                   'fixed_files': fixedfile})
df
```

For second part, this will filter only those bugs with two or more files.

```
newdf = df[df.fixed_files.str.len() >= 2]
```

If want bugs with exactly 2 and 3 files then:

```
newdf = df[(df.fixed_files.str.len() == 2) | (df.fixed_files.str.len() == 3)]
```

Comment: I try this and it works correctly. Thank you very much!!! But  before I go to my second problem, is there any way to put each <file> in a list [] like this :[[com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.java],[com.google.zxing.client.android.PreferencesActivity.java]]
?

Comment: @MarcOuédraogo the fixedfile var is already a list of lists.

Comment: @CodeMonkey, I have just understood now. You are amazing!

Comment: Concerning my second problem, sincerly I have no idea to do that :(

being able to select for example all tags that have 2 or 3 fixedfile.

Comment: @tdelaney, your solution also work well! Thank you very much!

Comment: @MarcOuédraogo updated answer to filter those with 2 or 3 fixed files.

Comment: !!!OMG, I have to improve my level! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

The below collects the data. The idea is to find all `bug` elements and iterate over them. For each `bug` - look for the required sub elements.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0"?>

<bugrepository name="AspectJ">
  <bug id="28974" opendate="2003-1-3 10:28:00" fixdate="2003-1-14 14:30:00">
    <buginformation>
      <summary>"Compiler error when introducing a ""final"" field"</summary>
      <description>The aspecs the problem...</description>
    </buginformation>
    <fixedFiles>
      <file>org.aspectj/modules/weaver/src/org/aspectj/weaver/AjcMemberMaker.java</file>
    </fixedFiles>
  </bug>

  <bug id="28919" opendate="2002-12-30 16:40:00" fixdate="2003-1-14 15:06:00">
    <buginformation>
      <summary>waever tries to weave into native methods ...</summary>
      <description>If youat org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.burce</description>
    </buginformation>
    <fixedFiles>
      <file>org.aspectj/modules/weaver/src/org/aspectj/weaver/bcel/LazyMethodGen.java</file>
    </fixedFiles>
  </bug>
  
  <bug id="29186" opendate="2003-1-8 21:22:00" fixdate="2003-1-14 16:43:00">
    <buginformation>
      <summary>ajc -emacssym chokes on pointcut that includes an intertype method</summary>
      <description>This ;void Foo.ajc$before$Foo</description>
    </buginformation>
    <fixedFiles>
      <file>org.aspectj/modules/weaver/src/org/aspectj/weaver/Lint.java</file>
      <file>org.aspectj/modules/weaver/src/org/aspectj/weaver/Shadow.java</file>
      <file>org.aspectj/modules/weaver/src/org/aspectj/weaver/bcel/BcelWeaver.java</file>
    </fixedFiles>
  </bug>
  
  <bug id="29769" opendate="2003-1-19 11:42:00" fixdate="2003-1-24 21:17:00">
    <buginformation>
      <summary>Ajde does not support new AspectJ 1.1 compiler options</summary>
      <description>The org.aspectj.ajpiler. This enhancement is needed byort.</description>
    </buginformation>
    <fixedFiles>
      <file>org.aspectj/modules/ajde/testdata/examples/figures-coverage/figures/Figure.java</file>
      <file>org.aspectj/modules/ajde/testsrc/org/aspectj/ajde/AjdeTests.java</file>
      <file>org.aspectj/modules/ajde/testsrc/org/aspectj/ajde/ui/StructureViewManagerTest.java</file>
      <file>org.aspectj/modules/org.aspectj.ajdt.core/src/org/aspectj/ajdt/ajc/BuildArgParser.java</file>
      <file>org.aspectj/modules/org.aspectj.ajdt.core/src/org/aspectj/ajdt/internal/core/builder/AjBuildConfig.java</file>
      <file>org.aspectj/modules/org.aspectj.ajdt.core/testsrc/org/aspectj/ajdt/ajc/BuildArgParserTestCase.java</file>
    </fixedFiles>
  </bug>
  <bug id="29959" opendate="2003-1-22 7:10:00" fixdate="2003-2-13 16:00:00">
    <buginformation>
      <summary>super call in intertype method declaration body causes VerifyError</summary>
      <description>AspectJ Compiler 1.1 showstopper</description>
    </buginformation>
    <fixedFiles>
      <file>org.aspectj/modules/org.aspectj.ajdt.core/src/org/compiler/ast/InterTypeConstructorDeclaration.java</file>
      <file>org.aspectj/modules/org.aspectj.ajdt.core/src/org/aspectj/ajdt/internal/compiler/ast/SuperFixerVisitor.java</file>
      <file>org.aspectj/modules/org.aspectj.ajdt.core/src/org/aspectj/ajdt/internal/compiler/lookup/InterTypeMethodBinding.java</file>
      <file>org.aspectj/modules/tests/bugs/SuperToIntro.java</file>
    </fixedFiles>
  </bug>
  </bugrepository>'''

data = []
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for bug in root.findall('.//bug'):
    bug_info = bug.find('buginformation')
    fixed_files = bug.find('fixedFiles')
    entry = {'summary': bug_info.find('summary').text,'description':bug_info.find('summary').text,'fixedFiles':[x.text for x in list(fixed_files)]}
    data.append(entry)
for entry in data:
    print(entry)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

output

```
{'summary': '"Compiler error when introducing a ""final"" field"', 'description': '"Compiler error when introducing a ""final"" field"', 'fixedFiles': ['org.aspectj/modules/weaver/src/org/aspectj/weaver/AjcMemberMaker.java']}
{'summary': 'waever tries to weave into native methods ...', 'description': 'waever tries to weave into native methods ...', 'fixedFiles': ['org.aspectj/modules/weaver/src/org/aspectj/weaver/bcel/LazyMethodGen.java']}
{'summary': 'ajc -emacssym chokes on pointcut that includes an intertype method', 'description': 'ajc -emacssym chokes on pointcut that includes an intertype method', 'fixedFiles': ['org.aspectj/modules/weaver/src/org/aspectj/weaver/Lint.java', 'org.aspectj/modules/weaver/src/org/aspectj/weaver/Shadow.java', 'org.aspectj/modules/weaver/src/org/aspectj/weaver/bcel/BcelWeaver.java']}
{'summary': 'Ajde does not support new AspectJ 1.1 compiler options', 'description': 'Ajde does not support new AspectJ 1.1 compiler options', 'fixedFiles': ['org.aspectj/modules/ajde/testdata/examples/figures-coverage/figures/Figure.java', 'org.aspectj/modules/ajde/testsrc/org/aspectj/ajde/AjdeTests.java', 'org.aspectj/modules/ajde/testsrc/org/aspectj/ajde/ui/StructureViewManagerTest.java', 'org.aspectj/modules/org.aspectj.ajdt.core/src/org/aspectj/ajdt/ajc/BuildArgParser.java', 'org.aspectj/modules/org.aspectj.ajdt.core/src/org/aspectj/ajdt/internal/core/builder/AjBuildConfig.java', 'org.aspectj/modules/org.aspectj.ajdt.core/testsrc/org/aspectj/ajdt/ajc/BuildArgParserTestCase.java']}
{'summary': 'super call in intertype method declaration body causes VerifyError', 'description': 'super call in intertype method declaration body causes VerifyError', 'fixedFiles': ['org.aspectj/modules/org.aspectj.ajdt.core/src/org/compiler/ast/InterTypeConstructorDeclaration.java', 'org.aspectj/modules/org.aspectj.ajdt.core/src/org/aspectj/ajdt/internal/compiler/ast/SuperFixerVisitor.java', 'org.aspectj/modules/org.aspectj.ajdt.core/src/org/aspectj/ajdt/internal/compiler/lookup/InterTypeMethodBinding.java', 'org.aspectj/modules/tests/bugs/SuperToIntro.java']}
```

Comment: @tdelaney I agree with the comment. Explanation was added.

Comment: It also works, for me. Thank you very much!